# Iterating through multiple values in a hash and returning a value

Tags: ruby

I have a hash:

```
  hash_example = {777 =>[dog,brown,3], 123=>[cat,orange,2]}
```

I want to go through the hash array value and determine based on the third element which pet is the oldest age. I would choose the `max` for my method, the part where I figure out which value is associated with `max` and returning it to the screen is the part I am not getting, or am I completly lost? I threw the third value in there for educational purpose on how to compare different elements of the array.

```
b = hash_example.values.max{|k,b,c| b<=>c } 
print b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max` iterates all items returned by values and each item is an array itself. That's the point you are missing.

```
> hash_example.values
# => [["dog", "brown", 3], ["cat", "orange", 2]]
```

`max` doesn't return the value you are comparing against, instead, it returns the item that satisfies the comparison. What does it mean in practice? Here's the "working" version of your script

```
> hash_example.values.max{|a,b| a[2]<=>b[2] }
# => ["dog", "brown", 3]
```

As you can see, the returned value is the full item not the element used for the comparison. If you only want the third element you have to use `inject`.

```
> hash_example.values.inject(0) {|t,i| i[2] > t ? i[2] : t }
# => 3
```

Comment: Yours is the better analysis and the better solution. I withdraw.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explination. It makes alot more sense now!

Answer (score 3):

In ruby 1.8.7 there is a nice max_by method.

```
hash_example.values.max_by {|a| a[2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Greg Dan's response for earlier versions of Ruby.

```
hash_example.values.collect{|a|a[2]}.max
```

Comment: how do I take my value from max and return a different element in the same array? Obviously dog is 3 for .max but how do I puts that becasue the element in that array is .max I want to know print the string Dog? I didn't fully understand the .inject block